# Difference in address representation of a local value when observing the esp register using gdb

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb

I am running an already compiled simple program using gdb, this is the source code (I don't know with what flags the program was compiled)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  volatile int modified;
  char buffer[64];
  modified = 0;
  gets(buffer);

  if(modified != 0) {
     printf("you have changed the 'modified' variable\n");
  } else {
    printf("Try again?\n");
}
```

}

This code is taken from [propstar (stack-zero)](https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-zero/)

I am degbugging and getting to the instruction: `mov DWORD PTR [ESP+5C], 0x0`
And I do understand that this is the instantiation of the variable "modified"

When I am looking at the variable itself: `p &modified` the address is different from where is sitting on the stack see snapshot below:

[image: snapshot]

I do understand that the $esp is a pointer register, but I am not sure then how to read then addresses of the $esp when doing 'x/32wx $esp (see marked). I mean I would expect that if the esp is now holding address 0xbffffcc0 - it would be the address of the variable modified, since it is saved on the stack, but instead when I do 'p &modified' I fet the address 0xbffffd84.

[image: anapshp 2]

Thank you !

Comment: I assume that the exercise is about buffer overflows? Otherwise you should ***never ever*** use `gets`. It's not even part of the C standard since the C11 standard (released in 2011).

Answer (score 0):

For who is wonder, yes indeed this is for bufferoveflow practice and learning.

After writing the question and posting I guess it was my "Rubber duck debugging".

I relaunched again the the program with gdb, i checked again the stack with "x/32wx $esp" i see some value in address 0xbffffcc0, then when I got to the instruction i was stuggling with I checked again and saw that indeed the value there also changes to 0x0000000.
I am always forgetting the a 32/64 bit address is a representation of single byte, and so I did 0xbfffffcc0 - 0x4 = which does not fit to my address.
Then with a better looking I see that the x/32w $esp is actually representing me the stack from the bottom of it.
Since I recall that modified "is a local variable local vairable located in frame offset 92" i just did "x/100w $esp", i did find the address of the modified and for making sure i am correct i set this vairable with 0xffffffff ( 'set modified  = 0xffffffff ').

And indeed I saw the change where i expected (and not in where $esp is now).
I did read the 'mov DWORD PTR' is an access to as a pointer and know it needs to see it as a DWORD (32 bits), and not to change $esp value, since we did not push anything onto the stack.

[image: example]
Taken from [here](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Eevans/cs216/guides/x86.html)

I guess i need a break from debugging, thank you to whoever gave a look at my question.